# spring boot cache not support kotlin?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, redis, kotlin

I'm try to replace some java code with kotlin.

Such as jpa or cache.

The Start class is:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java)
}
```

The simple controller:

```
@RestController
class CacheController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var cache: CacheService

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    fun save(@PathVariable id: Long) {
        cache.save(id)
    }
}
```

CacheService:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = arrayOf("longCacheManager"), cacheManager = "longCacheManager")
open class CacheService {

    @Cacheable(key = "#id")
    fun save(id: Long): Long {
        return id
    }
}
```

cacheManager:

```
@Configuration
open class CacheConfig {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("longCacheManager")
    open fun longCacheManager(): CacheManager {
        val redisTemplate = StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory)
        redisTemplate.valueSerializer = GenericToStringSerializer(Long::class.java)
        val cacheManager = RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate)
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true)
        return cacheManager
    }
}
```

I can confirm the parameter of id entered in CacheService's method save, but after I have excute the PutMethod, there is nothing in redis.

When I write the cacheServie with java like this, the redis would be save what I want.

The Java cache service like this:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "longCacheManager", cacheManager = "longCacheManager")
public class JavaCacheService {

    @Cacheable(key = "#id")
    public Long save(Long id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I have also read some article like this:
https://pathtogeek.com/spring-boot-caching-with-kotlin

My SpringBootVersion is `1.5.3.RELEASE`
and kotlinVersion is `1.1.3-2`

Comment: Without `@EnableCaching` those annotations are pretty much useless. Which is also quite clearly explained in the article you linked to.

Comment: The @EnableCaching is in the start class which contain    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

Comment: Add it to your question for completeness.

Comment: Why is your Configuration/ cacheManager class written in Java and everything else in Kotlin?

Comment: @M.Deinum Has been added

Comment: @JKLy This project is write in java before, I want to use some kotlin in this. And part of the code has not been completely replaced. I try to writ Configuration/cacheManager in kotlin, Still don't have any effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all, I have fix it by make the cache method open

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = arrayOf("longCacheManager"), cacheManager = "longCacheManager")
open class CacheService {

    @Cacheable(key = "#id.toString()")
    open fun save(id: Long): Long {
        return id
    }
}
```

Spring generated proxy with cglib.

It must mandatory inherit the classes and methods.

But kotlin default is `final class` and method which without the keyword `open`.

Comment: If you use the kotlin-spring Gradle plugin it will make Spring annotated members `open` at build time without having to change the code to work with the framework: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin

Comment: Thanks, then I also saw the corresponding articles.But still not work in the unit test(such as mock). If there is a corresponding unit test case

Comment: Mockito 2 now supports mocking final members. See here: http://hadihariri.com/2016/10/04/Mocking-Kotlin-With-Mockito/ It's also now slightly easier than described in the blog post because all you need to do is add this dependency to the test scope: `org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47`

Comment: Is really thank you for your answer，`mockito-inline` solved can't mocking final members problem.